# Outputting a graph in VBA based off an inputted range

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine, excel-charts

I'm trying to get my VBA code to output a graph in excel based on an inputted range that was selected using a user defined function from multiple cells. I've passed the data to the sub as a range but it ends up assuming that the range is two data sets rather than one data set with x and y values. The data set is selected from excel into a function that is being written separately which then calls the sub.

```
Sub CreateChart(ByRef r As Range)
Dim cht As Object

  Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2
  cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=r
  cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

End Sub
```

I called the sub through

```
Call CreateChart(r)
```

with r being a two column range of data that was selected from excel.

```
Public Function cubic(ByVal r As Range, x As Double, Optional check As Integer = 1) As Double
```

The overall function code is here as well

```
Public Function cubic(ByVal r As Range, x As Double, Optional check As Integer = 1) As Double
    Dim data() As Double
    Dim check1 As Integer
    Dim Smatrix() As Double
    Dim Tmatrix() As Double
    Dim Xmatrix() As Double
    Dim Amatrix() As Double
    Dim Hmatrix() As Double
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    m = r.Rows.Count
    ReDim data(1 To m, 2)
    ReDim Smatrix(1 To m, 1 To m)
    ReDim Tmatrix(1 To m, 4)
    ReDim Xmatrix(1 To m)
    ReDim Amatrix(1 To m - 1, 1 To 4)
    ReDim Hmatrix(1 To m)

    check1 = Test(check)
    
    For i = 1 To m
        data(i, 1) = r(i, 1).Value
        data(i, 2) = r(i, 2).Value
    Next i
    
    Smatrix(1, 1) = 1
    Smatrix(m, m) = 1
    
    For i = 1 To m - 1
        Hmatrix(i) = data(i + 1, 1) - data(i, 1)
    Next i
    
    If check1 = 2 Then
        Smatrix(1, 2) = -1
        Smatrix(m, m - 1) = -1
    End If
    
    For i = 2 To m - 1
        Smatrix(i, i - 1) = Hmatrix(i - 1)
        Smatrix(i, i + 1) = Hmatrix(i)
        Smatrix(i, i) = 2 * (Hmatrix(i - 1) + Hmatrix(i))
    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To m - 1
        Tmatrix(i, 4) = 6 * ((data(i + 1, 2) - data(i, 2)) / Hmatrix(i) - (data(i, 2) - data(i - 1, 2)) / Hmatrix(i - 1))
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To m
        If i <> 1 Then
            Tmatrix(i, 1) = Smatrix(i, i - 1)
        End If
        
        Tmatrix(i, 2) = Smatrix(i, i)
        
        If i <> m Then
            Tmatrix(i, 3) = Smatrix(i, i + 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To m
        Tmatrix(i, 1) = Tmatrix(i, 1) / Tmatrix(i - 1, 2)
        Tmatrix(i, 2) = Tmatrix(i, 2) - Tmatrix(i, 1) * Tmatrix(i - 1, 3)
        Tmatrix(i, 4) = Tmatrix(i, 4) - Tmatrix(i, 1) * Tmatrix(i - 1, 4)
    Next i
    
    Xmatrix(m) = Tmatrix(m, 4) / Tmatrix(m, 2)
    For i = m - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Xmatrix(i) = (Tmatrix(i, 4) - Tmatrix(i, 3) * Xmatrix(i + 1)) / Tmatrix(i, 2)
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To m - 1
        Amatrix(i, 1) = (Xmatrix(i + 1) - Xmatrix(i)) / 6 * Hmatrix(i)
        Amatrix(i, 2) = Xmatrix(i) / 2
        Amatrix(i, 3) = (data(i + 1, 2) - data(i, 2)) / Hmatrix(i) - Hmatrix(i) * Xmatrix(i) / 2 - Hmatrix(i) * (Xmatrix(i + 1) - Xmatrix(i)) / 6
        Amatrix(i, 4) = data(i, 2)
    Next i
    If x < data(1, 1) Or x > data(m, 1) Then
        Call Check2(x)
        If x < data(1, 1) Then
            cubic = Amatrix(1, 1) * (x - data(1, 1)) ^ 3 + Amatrix(1, 2) * (x - data(1, 1)) ^ 2 + Amatrix(1, 3) * (x - data(1, 1)) + Amatrix(1, 4)
        ElseIf x > data(m, 1) Then
            cubic = Amatrix(m - 1, 1) * (x - data(m - 1, 1)) ^ 3 + Amatrix(m - 1, 2) * (x - data(m - 1, 1)) ^ 2 + Amatrix(m - 1, 3) * (x - data(m - 1, 1)) + Amatrix(m - 1, 4)
        End If
    ElseIf x = data(m, 1) Then
        cubic = data(m, 2)
    Else
        For i = 1 To m - 1
            If data(i, 1) < x And x < data(i + 1, 1) Then
                cubic = Amatrix(i, 1) * (x - data(i, 1)) ^ 3 + Amatrix(i, 2) * (x - data(i, 1)) ^ 2 + Amatrix(i, 3) * (x - data(i, 1)) + Amatrix(i, 4)
            ElseIf x = data(i, 1) Then
                cubic = data(i, 2)
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    Call CreateChart(r)
End Function
```

As well as the subroutine and function called within the function that haven't been posted

```
Public Function Test(check As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Response As Integer
    If check = 1 Then
        Response = MsgBox("Boundary Condition 1 selected, is this correct (select No for boundary condition 2)?", vbYesNo, "Boundary Conditions")
        If Response = 6 Then
            Test = 1
        Else
            Test = 2
        End If
    ElseIf check = 2 Then
        Response = MsgBox("Boundary Condition 2 selected, is this correct (select No for boundary condition 1)?", vbYesNo, "Boundary Conditions")
        If Response = 6 Then
            Test = 2
        Else
            Test = 1
        End If
    Else
        Response = MsgBox("Incorrect Boundary Condition, select Yes for condition 1 and No for condition 2", vbYesNo, "Boundary Conditions")
        If Response = 6 Then
            Test = 1
        Else
            Test = 2
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

```
Public Sub Check2(x)
    MsgBox ("Value given is outside data range, answer may not be correct, extrapolating from calculated polynomial")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share how you're calling this ([edit] your question with the code)?

Comment: I edited it to show

Comment: Well it's important to show us *exactly* what `r` is, right? That's key to reproducing the issue ;-)

Comment: fair point lol. r is just two columns of data I selected from excel.

Comment: does it work if you do it manually after selecting the range? and showing in the code how `r` is set could still be helpful. oftentimes we think we are doing something but what we write in code is slightly different and our eyes can no longer see it.

Comment: r isn't set in any particular way. In the original function it is just ByVal r as range. What do you mean by do it manually? Currently the range is manually selected as part of the function in excel =function(range)

Comment: It's through a public function. r is never set equal to anything within the code. I added the closest thing I could think of in the code. r is selected from excel cells through the function. Within that function is where the sub is called

Comment: Apologies, I deleted my previous comments as I was completely wrong. Creating a chart is not regarded as changing the structure of a worksheet. I tested your code and works perfectly as it is when called from a worksheet cell. I do not know why it is not working for you, but without looking at your `cubic` function it is just guess work.

Comment: It wasn't clear in the question (and the back-and-forth in comments) that you're calling this as a User-Defined Function called from a cell. I echo @SuperSymmetry though, we need more detail in order to be able to reproduce the issue. Sample data or a screenshot would help, as would the rest of `cubic`.

Comment: VBA is very new to me so my apologies there. Here is a sample excel sheet https://imgur.com/a/Q6EooCt as well as the code itself https://imgur.com/a/9inVf1n. I've added the  `cubic` code as well to the original post to see if that can help. Thanks for all the patience while I struggle to explain the problem @BigBen @Super Symmetry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Sub CreateChart(ByRef r As Range)
    Dim cht As Object
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(XlChartType:=xlXYScatterSmooth)
    cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=r
End Sub
```